# update a page automatically with jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh

i have been testing a 'jquery' script that automatically updates a page every n seconds ,it works fine in all browsers except for internet explorer it doesn't load the  page 'posts.php' and it doesn't show any errors 
code for reference

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#responsecontainer").load("posts.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('posts.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 2000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many sites I have found have suggested that **IE** may be caching your code

```
  $("#responsecontainer").load("posts.php" + new Date().getTime());
```

Try this ..It may or maynot solve the issue but will let us know about **Caching** problem

See [this](http://zacster.blogspot.com/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html) for more info.